# Permutations of two lists with each three different outcomes (32,000 combinations)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations, permutation, distribution

There are 50 Success Criteria (“requirements”) broken into two levels: Single-A (with 25 requirements) and Double-A (with 12 requirements). Using the philosophy of the distributive property, I need to create a sort of permutated list of all possible combinations from these two levels. The trouble I’m running into, though, there are various make ups of the levels themselves against one of three conformance levels.

A reviewer will go through each of the Success Criteria to fill out a VPAT. A VPAT will have the 50 Success Criteria listed out and my reviewer will look at the product, and based on the given success criteria, give it a result of “Does Not Support”, “Partially Supports”, or “Supports”. Each line can have only one result.
So, a completed review could look like this:

| Requirement # | Level | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Single-A | SUPPORTS |
| 2 | Single-A | SUPPORTS |
| 3 | Single-A | PARTIALLY SUPPORTS |
| 4 | Single-A | DOES NOT SUPPORT |
| 5 | Single-A | DOES NOT SUPPORT |
| 11 | Double-A | DOES NOT SUPPORT |
| 12 | Double-A | PARTIALLY SUPPORTS |
| 13 | Double-A | SUPPORTS |
| 14 | Double-A | PARTIALLY SUPPORTS |

The final tally, is what I’m trying to summarize (tab “Intended Result”). Every VPAT should output a pivoted result like this:

| Single A Fail | Single A Partial | Single A Pass | Double A Fail | Double A Partial | Double A Pass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 12 |

Here’s my problem. There are 351 permutations for the Single A list and 91 for the Double A list. I’ve already mapped those out manually in the given tabs. Now, I need to permutate both lists by their three dimensions (nearly 32,000 possibilities), but I can’t figure it out with the several dimensions. Here’s the “distributive property”: From the Single-A list, row #1, I need to line up with all 91 of the Double-A list. Then, do it again for line #2 to all 91 lines. And on and on. [See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQkB5.png).

Can anyone help me with a formula that might be able to accomplish this without me copying 91 lines 361 times and doing a bunch of “fill downs”? [Attached](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yq3yLMlFj3LSxtmCohJOtPmTr2oQVXmx/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=113236631457805430717&rtpof=true&sd=true), as well, is my workbook so far.

I've tried the various permutation formulas, but I'm getting the "number" of combinations that are possible, not the actual results. I'd like to list out every possible scenario for both lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's helpful. I think solved it through Google Sheets, through this formula:

=REDUCE({SINGLE_A!A1:D1,DOUBLE_A!A1:D1},SEQUENCE(COUNTA(SINGLE_A!A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,b,{a;
SCAN(,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(DOUBLE_A!A2:A)),LAMBDA(c,d,{INDEX(SINGLE_A!A2:D,b),INDEX(DOUBLE_A!A2:D,d)}))}))

The problem is can't be replicated in Excel... but if you only need the values, you can download it as an .XLSX and it will keep the values without the formula.

[image]

As you can see, there are 31491 combinations. Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eqmAfiSO_mMn8eQYZIW3szithg0YZAP_ttmjBf7EkpE/edit#gid=913633539)

Answer (score 0):

### Permutate Rows of Two Tables

- Feel free to download the file from [`my Google Drive`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uJUC1BxhZoR0eHXw1HBAqjbe12PggGlL/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102807120054526711184&rtpof=true&sd=true).

**LAMBDA**

```
=LAMBDA(Table1,Table2,LET(Data1,DROP(Table1,1),Data2,DROP(Table2,1),
    rCount1,ROWS(Data1),cCount1,COLUMNS(Data1),rCount2,ROWS(Data2),cCount2,COLUMNS(Data2),rCount,rCount1*rCount2,
    Result1,WRAPCOLS(INDEX(TOCOL(Data1,,1),ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(rCount*cCount1,,1)/rCount2,0)),rCount),
    Result2,WRAPROWS(INDEX(TOCOL(Data2),MOD(SEQUENCE(rCount*cCount2,,1)-1,rCount2*cCount2)+1),cCount2),
VSTACK(HSTACK(TAKE(Table1,1),TAKE(Table2,1)),HSTACK(Result1,Result2))))(A1:C4,E1:G5)
```

**`PermutRows` Function (`Formulas->Name Manager->New`)**

```
=LAMBDA(Table1,Table2,LET(Data1,DROP(Table1,1),Data2,DROP(Table2,1),
    rCount1,ROWS(Data1),cCount1,COLUMNS(Data1),rCount2,ROWS(Data2),cCount2,COLUMNS(Data2),rCount,rCount1*rCount2,
    Result1,WRAPCOLS(INDEX(TOCOL(Data1,,1),ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(rCount*cCount1,,1)/rCount2,0)),rCount),
    Result2,WRAPROWS(INDEX(TOCOL(Data2),MOD(SEQUENCE(rCount*cCount2,,1)-1,rCount2*cCount2)+1),cCount2),
VSTACK(HSTACK(TAKE(Table1,1),TAKE(Table2,1)),HSTACK(Result1,Result2))))
```

```
=PermutRows(A1:C4,E1:G5)
```

**Using Your Tables**

```
=PermutRows(Table2[[#All];[A_FAIL]:[A_PASS]];Table1[[#All];[AA_FAIL]:[AA_PASS]])
```

[image]

**Helper Formulas**

```
J2: =TOCOL(A2:C4,,1)
K2: =ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(36,,1)/4,0)
L2: =INDEX(J2#,K2#)
M2: =WRAPCOLS(L2#,12)
Q2: =TOCOL(E2:G5,,0)
R2: =MOD(SEQUENCE(36,,1)-1,12)+1
S2: =INDEX(Q2#,R2#)
T2: =WRAPROWS(S2#,3)
X2: =HSTACK(M2#,T2#)
```